# VSCode - disable comments auto-formatting for C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

I just installed an extension prettier in vscode to autoformat my code. However all the comments in my code are being moved towards the left. Which I don't want.
Before formatting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ux9e.png)

After formatting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFMee.png)

The thing is I want my comments to stay exactly where they were before. I don't want them being moved. Other things I'm absolutely fine with. I just want the comments to be ignored when formatting.

Is it even possible? If so could you help me with this? It doesn't have to be only with Prettier extension. I'm down to use other formatting extensions if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a certain amount of spaces after code for comments?

Comment: If it is possible to do, then yes. That would help a lot

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805558/is-there-a-way-to-use-clang-format-to-do-indentation-only/64806815#64806815

Comment: Glad I could help, Ill post an answer for people, make sure to mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VSCode, you can edit your settings.json file to specify your default clang format fallback style. This documentation will tell you all parameters you can use for the setting: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

For reference, my setting:

```
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": " {BasedOnStyle: Google, AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true, AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true, AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All, AlignTrailingComments: true, Language: Cpp, AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None, PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 9999, PointerAlignment: Left, SortIncludes: true, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0, BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 5, AlignAfterOpenBracket: true, AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true, AlignConsecutiveMacros : true}",
```

Answer (score 0):

With [this site](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) description, you should set the 'ReflowComments' keyword to false, and here is my personal setting in setting.json

mysetting:

```
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{BasedOnStyle: Google,IndentWidth: 4,ReflowComments: false}"
```